# D3 - append('foreignObject') only adds a text and tspan element

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

So this is driving me nuts :(. I'm generating a svg document using D3 and then rendering it in phantomJs and saving the output as .svg.

In the code, I'm generating a `foreignObject` as follows:

`svg.select("#def-commit")
        .append('foreignObject')
        .attr('width', 100)
        .attr('height', 100)
        .attr('x', 50)
        .attr('y', 50)
        .attr('requiredFeatures','http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility')
            .append('xhtml:p')
            .text("a big chunk of text that should wrap");`

Now the weird thing is that the generated document doesn't have the `foreignObject` node in the DOM at all. instead, what it has is an `text` and a nested `tspan`. Like so:

`<g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="def-commit">
    <circle r="15" cx="0" cy="0"/>
    <text xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><tspan style="font-size: 11.5pt; font-family: &quot;sans-serif&quot;;" x="0" y="14.5">a big chunk of text that should wrap</tspan>
</text>
</g>`

What am I missing?

Other info:
D3 - latest - 3.5.16
SVG declaration

`<svg xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="mermaidChart0" width="1200" height="904.0178571428571" style="width: 1192; height: 904.0178571428571;" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this turned out to be a big wild goose chase!

A little bit of background - I'm trying to add a diagram to [mermaid](https://github.com/knsv/mermaid).

There is code in the mermaid repo that scans through the svg and replaces all foreignObjects with text/tspan :) Just that I never imagined something like that and I have no clue why I just didn't grep the source as I usually do!

In case someone does land here (though I doubt it) - it's here at ['lib/phantomscript.js'](https://github.com/knsv/mermaid/blob/master/lib/phantomscript.js#L104-L108)

Thanks for reading.